Why do I get a syntax error when I invoke the chain question?
I've tried multiple versions of SQL query chains on a small SQLite database (263k rows) but I keep getting an SQLite error when I invoke the chain question. It will produce the query but then when it runs it fails:
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain

chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
response = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})
response


OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "CNS_SEX_AGE_RACE"; ": syntax error [SQL: sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "CNS_SEX_AGE_RACE"; ] (Background on this
error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

